# Is it possible to pump water up beyond limits of a pipe's pressure capacity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I was thinking, in an open system, one could pump water up past a pipe's pressure capacity if you just pump it up to a reservoir to a height that is less than the pipe's pressure capacity, and then pump up the water further from that reservoir to the next one.  The following picture describes what I am talking about.

[image: open system diagram]

My question is, can this be done in a closed system, where the reservoir is not exposed to the external atmosphere?  Would it matter if a thick valve is used to try and isolate the succeeding columns, or would the pressure still transfer from the upper column of water to the lower column of water?

As it is a closed system, there would have to be a loop at each level so as the water is pumped up, a gas (water vapour) would be pumped down.  Something like this:
[image: closed pump system with reservoirs]
The white boxes are the reservoirs. The green pipes would pump liquid water up.  The pink pipes would allow gaseous water vapour down. On each end of each pipe, you could have a heavy valve which can open and close.  Actually, would such a valve be even necessary?  With this configuration, the height of the column is now just the height of each pipe for pumping water up, right?  But if that were the case, then you could just have a pipe that would go up, down, and then up again.  Is the gas doing something or am I missing something?

Comment: It seems to me to be an engineering question.

Comment: Might be an engineering question if I knew if it was possible.  I'm asking theoretically if it is @annav.

Comment: But you need a lot of engineering input, what is the "pressure capacity of  a pipe". will the pipe burst of over capacity? an engineer would know that.

Comment: @annav, assume that it will burst, and it is the pressure that would do so would be the pressure at the bottom of a column of water of $x$ meters. So, I want to only go up some value that is less than $x$ meters at each stage.

Comment: If you arrange it so that the water pumps for the first green pipe and the second green pipe pump water up at the same rate, then you don't need the yellow gas pipes since the total volume of water (and gas) in each white box will remain time-independent.

Comment: But will the pressure of the bottom of the fist pipe be that of a column of water of just the first green pipe, or the sum of the first and second green pipe @SamuelWeir?  Assume that the pump is at the bottom of each green pipe.

Comment: The pressure at the bottom of the first pipe should be just due to the column of water in the first pipe. Furthermore, to simplify things further, you could just have one very long vertical green pipe with water pumps spaced every 25 feet or so, which would enable you to eliminate the white boxes. Such a pipe should work in pumping water to an indefinite height without exceeding the strength of the pipe provided that the pumps are all working together and pumping at the proper rates.

Comment: @SamuelWeir, what if a pump were to fail?  Is there a way to isolate the two water columns from each other?  Would a value do that?

Comment: Yes, the big practical problem I see with such a very long vertical pipe scheme, though, is what happens if a pump fails. If that happens, then the burden falls on the remaining working pumps to work at the proper pumping speeds to make sure that the strength of the pipe is not exceeded. In that sense, your initial sketch is more fault-proof. If a pump in your initial sketch fails and the water starts to flow back down a pipe, then the water can just overflow the "bucket" at the bottom of the pipe without putting any extra stresses on any pipes below.

Comment: Well then @SamuelWeir, write down the answer and I'll give you the checkmark.